# Как в с++ получить имя типа переменной?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Помогите получить имя типа переменной.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну, нечто похожее - хотя не всегда точно и не всегда (вернее, не везде - в зависимости от компилятора) понятно - дает

```
typeid(var).name()
```

См., например, [здесь](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid). Но лучшего в стандарте не предусмотрено...

Comment: При вывоед например `typeid(var).name()` выводится только первая буква типа.

Comment: @АндрейСаламов Это зависит от конкретного компилятора (в стандарте не оговаривается конкретный вывод). Там, где информация выводится в таком зашифрованном виде - есть соответствующие улититы-дешифровщики. Поскольку я пользуюсь Visual Studio, а он выводит в удобочитаемом виде, как именно называются соответствующие утилиты, скажем, в G++ - не помню.

Comment: Так и есть, я на `XCode`, пересмотрел от `C++11` до `C++17`, все так же.

Answer (score 5):

Используйте `typeid` - вывод типа времени выполнения:

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <typeinfo.h>  

class Base 
{  
public:  
    virtual void vvfunc() {}  
};  

class Derived : public Base {};  

using namespace std;  
int main() 
{  
   Derived* pd = new Derived;  
   Base* pb = pd;  
   cout << typeid( pb ).name() << endl;   //prints "class Base *"  
   cout << typeid( *pb ).name() << endl;   //prints "class Derived"  
   cout << typeid( pd ).name() << endl;   //prints "class Derived *"  
   cout << typeid( *pd ).name() << endl;   //prints "class Derived"  
   delete pd;  
}
```

Результат `std::type_info::name` ненадежен (проблема возникает при выводе типа аргумента шаблонной функции, например, а именно - тип аргумента рассматривается как если бы он был передан в шаблонную функцию по значению). Более точный ответ даст функция из фреймворка boost из `<typeindex>` (без отбрасывания `const`, `volatile` и `&`):

```
// In header: <boost/type_index.hpp>

template<typename T> type_index type_id_with_cvr();
```

Особенность ее в том, что она возвращает имя типа **НЕ** опуская ссылочность переменной и ее спецификаторы `const` и `volatile`. Вызывается она следующим образом:

```
type_index ti = type_id_with_cvr<int&>();
std::cout << ti.pretty_name();  // Outputs 'int&'
```

Пример использования `type_id_with_cvr` в шаблонной функции:

```
#include <boost/type_index.h> 

template<typename Т> 
void f(const Т& param)
{
    using std::cout;
    using boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr;

    cout << "Т : " << type_id_with_cvr<T>().pretty_name() << std::endl;
    cout << "param : " << type_id_with_cvr<decltype(param)>().pretty_пame() << std:endl;
}
```

Результатом работы будет выведен тип `X` в первом `cout` и тип `X const&` во втором.